# Create a Table with scrollable Header

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

There are thousands of articles about how to make a table with fixed header and scrollable body.

But I didn't find any about a table with scrollable header.

In my case there are a lot of columns and they don't have enough space on the screen, how can it be made to have a fixed width and be scrollable horizontally?

I've tried to include the `table` inside a `div`:

```
<div className="table-container">
  <table> ... </table>
</div>


.table-container {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out  [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp)

```css
.table-container {
  width: 50%;
overflow-x:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: sticky` however, be aware that this is not supported by older browsers.

```html
<div style="position: relative; top: 25px; left: 25px; width: 500px; height: 150px; overflow: auto;">

        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: silver;">Column 1</th>
                <th style="position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: silver;">Column 2</th>
                <th style="position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: silver;">Column 3</th>
                <th style="position: sticky; top: 0; background-color: silver;">Column 4</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="overflow: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1 Col 1</td><td>Row 1 Col 2</td><td>Row 1 Col 3</td><td>Row 1 Col 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Col 1</td><td>Row 2 Col 2</td><td>Row 2 Col 3</td><td>Row 2 Col 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 3 Col 1</td><td>Row 3 Col 2</td><td>Row 3 Col 3</td><td>Row 3 Col 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 4 Col 1</td><td>Row 4 Col 2</td><td>Row 4 Col 3</td><td>Row 4 Col 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 5 Col 1</td><td>Row 5 Col 2</td><td>Row 5 Col 3</td><td>Row 5 Col 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 6 Col 1</td><td>Row 6 Col 2</td><td>Row 6 Col 3</td><td>Row 6 Col 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 7 Col 1</td><td>Row 7 Col 2</td><td>Row 7 Col 3</td><td>Row 7 Col 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 8 Col 1</td><td>Row 8 Col 2</td><td>Row 8 Col 3</td><td>Row 8 Col 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 9 Col 1</td><td>Row 9 Col 2</td><td>Row 9 Col 3</td><td>Row 9 Col 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 10 Col 1</td><td>Row 10 Col 2</td><td>Row 10 Col 3</td><td>Row 10 Col 4</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```